# cassandra bad resultset when updating a table

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, batch-processing

I'm writing a code to update a whole table in cassandra.
I'm using fetchSize and setPagingState to read a "big" table per block (and avoid a timeout)
My problem is that it counts a number of lines higher than it should.
I suppose than when it updates some lines, it modifies the state and re read
Is there a tip to avoid this ?
In my case, a table has 400K rows and the traitment find 85 million lines

regards
Jean-Luc

```
          val insertPrepareStmt = userSession.prepare(s"INSERT INTO $table (id, value) VALUES (?, ?)")
       val stmt = userSession.prepare(s"SELECT id,value FROM $table").bind()
       var nextPage:Option[PagingState]=None
       var i:Int=0
       var nbConverted:Int=0
       do {
         nextPage match {
           case Some(p) => stmt. setPagingState(p)
           case _ =>
         }
         val rs= userSession.execute(stmt.setFetchSize(batchSize))
         nextPage=Option(rs.getExecutionInfo.getPagingState)
         // loop on rs
         for (row <- rs.all() )
         {
           val id=row.getString("id")
           val value =row.getByteArray("value")
    // modify value in newAvro
    val newAvrp= f(avro)
            userSession.executeAsync(insertPrepareStmt.bind(id,ByteBuffer.wrap(newAvro)))
            nbConverted+=1
           }
           i+=1
           if (i % 10000==0) logger.error(s"...number lines $i    number converted lines $nbConverted")
         }
       } while (nextPage.isDefined)
```

Answer (score 0):

After multi tests, first the insert statement do not disturb the paginated select.
The Resultset returned by cassandra has more rows than it should
The solution was to limit the resultset to the fetchsize

```
//for (row <- rs.all() )
for (row <- rs.take(batchSize) )
```